# Is there a work-around for ProgressBar.setProgress accepting an integer?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

So, my application is crashing because of "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2160000000", it is my understanding that the largest possible integer is 2,147,483,647. So, OBVIOUSLY it is crashing because I am trying to setProgress on the ProgressBar with an int that is too large.

My question is:  Is there a work around for this?
The int is that large because I am converting DAYS, HOURS, and MINUTES to millis.
So the application crashes when I enter any values larger than 24 DAYS, 20 HOURS, 31 MINUTES. (Anything above this is creating an integer too large to be accepted by setProgress.)

However, I need to be able to enter up to 32 days but I can't find any way to bypass this restrictive parameter to the CountDownTimer. I have posted some code below as well as some LogCat errors for supplemental information.

Thanks in advanced, guys!

---

Method that calculates where timer should be based on time stamp:

```
public int bsCalculation()                     LINE # 138
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    long currentTime = date.getMillis();

    long bsDiffInMillis;
    if(bsTimeStamp==0) {
        bsDiffInMillis = 0;
    }
    else {
        bsDiffInMillis = currentTime - bsTimeStamp;
        timeInputBs -= bsDiffInMillis;
    }


    int bsDiffInt = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(bsDiffInMillis));
    int roundedDiffBs = (bsDiffInt + 500) / 1000 * 1000;


    j += roundedDiffBs;

return j;
}
```

Method that converts input from EditText(s) and to millis:

```
public static Long getMillisForCrafting(long daysPh, long hoursPh, long minutesPh) {
                Locale.getDefault();
                DateTime bs = new DateTime();
                daysPulled = daysPh;
                hoursPulled = hoursPh;
                minutesPulled = minutesPh;

                final long nowInMillis = bs.getMillis();


                Long days = daysPulled * 86400000;
                Long hours = hoursPulled * 3600000;
                Long minutes = minutesPulled * 60000;
                Long millisToAddToNow = days + hours + minutes;
                Long futureDateInMillis = millisToAddToNow + nowInMillis;
                Long millisFromDate = futureDateInMillis - nowInMillis;

                return millisFromDate;
            }
```

Log Cat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2283): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2160000000"
E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at com.example.esomount.HomeActivity$bsTimer.onTick(HomeActivity.java:376)
E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
```

Comment: You don't need to exhibit progress to 32 bits of precision. Just use a coarser-grained measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason in the world to update progress once every millisecond. Take your millisecond time stamp and divide it by a few orders of magnitude to come up with an int value that's less than `int.maxSize()`.

Better yet, depending on how long you expect your progress bar to run, you can divide it up into 100 pieces, each representing 1% of your total progress. The point of the progress bar is to convey progress over time on a humanly perceptible scale -- there isn't anyone in the world who can accurately perceive 1000 updates a second.

Comment: Perfect, I can't believe that I tried doing it that way. I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you, friend.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use the ProgressBar to scale from 0 to 100, like percent, and then convert the time progress to a percent between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying millisecond resolution for a 32 day period is useless unless you have a display that's over 2 billion pixels wide.

Take the width (approximate is ok) of your progress bar and calculate a divisor for your max and current values.

For example, if my display is 960 pixels wide, and if the progress bar is full width, with no borders of any sort the finest granularity I can represent is 1/960<sup>th</sup> of the maximum value.

If I'm representing 32 days, that's 2,764,800,000 milliseconds. Divide that by 960 and you get 2,880,000. That is the time represented by a single pixel in milliseconds.

Therefore, you would `setMax(960)`, then `setProgress(yourValueInMillis/2880000)`.